# Where is the Linux (beta) option on my Acer Chromebook 15?

Tags: linux, chrome-book

I have searched every single video and photo on google, and could not find an answer. Usually the Linux (Beta) option would be in the settings..

Like in this photo:

[image: lok]

**and sometimes it would be under a developers tab..**

Like in this photo:

[image: bro]

**But for me, there was no Linux(Beta) option, and no developers tab..**

So my question is, is there another tab/option that I need to click on to find the Linux (Beta) option? Is it hiding in some section that I don't know about?

Comment: Don't Chromebooks have a developer mode that needs to enabled via UEFI (or something early-boot)? Maybe you need to do that before the Developers section comes up.

Comment: If chrome (made by google) is anything like Android (Also google) they've deliberately hidden it until you go through some "magic" sequence of tapping the screen to enable it.  On android that's going into the settings, help / about then tapping the software version about 20 times.  For chrome you might want to google [how to turn on chromebook developer mode](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+turn+on+chromebook+developer+mode&rlz=1C5CHFA_enGB918GB918&oq=chrome+book+show+developer&aqs=chrome.3.69i57j0i10i22i30j0i390l2.11911j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @PhilipCouling The developer mode didn't work. Good thing I kept my files in my Google Drive(warning it power washes your computer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your firmware version is listed below the [Bay Trail](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/docs/+/master/containers_and_vms.md#baytrail-systems) Systems (example: Google_**Banjo**.5216....), Linux won't be supported by your computer:

> Chromebooks using Intel’s BayTrail do not include [VT-x](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel%20VT-x). Yes, normally
> this CPU includes [VMX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel%20VT-x), but the variant in Chromebooks does not. Thus,
> unfortunately, they'll never be supported.

To find your firmware version:

1. Open a browser tab and enter the following URL: `chrome://os-settings/help`
2. Then, click on "Additional details"
3. On the "Build Details" line, click on the icon that says: "Copy build details to clipboard" when you hover over it.
4. Then paste (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>, or right-click Paste) the results in a document.

Comment: If Chromebooks needs `VT-x` to run Linux, it means you'll "get Linux" through virtualization means.